# How to copy specific page content and create child page?

Tags: pages, child-pages

I am using SOULMEDIC theme, but need to have full customized specified page, What is the best way to simplify and create a `page-{id}.php` in child folder? How to copy all content and simply edit in my newly created page? At the moment i think of copying source code from page and paste it, but is there any better way?

Comment: But i want to transfer some already created content on that page, using wp bakery visual composer. I just want to make specific changes to css of that page. Plius I don't have experiance in editing theme's framework workflow.

Comment: if you have a child theme, all files of the parent are inherited if you have no same file on your child... that is if you followed correctly on how to create a child theme...